# FastCGI with Symfony2 on IIS 6

Tags: php, iis, symfony, fastcgi

I'm having problems with getting Symfony2 working with FastCGI on IIS with PHP 5.3.10 VC9 Not thread safe, every time I load the page, I get:

```
FastCGI Error

The FastCGI Handler was unable to process the request.
Error Details:

The FastCGI process exited unexpectedly
Error Number: -2147467259 (0x80004005).
Error Description: Unspecified error
HTTP Error 500 - Server Error.
Internet Information Services (IIS)
```

I've been searching around the days and having my fast cgi configured as the following in `fcgiext.ini`:

```
EnvironmentVars=PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS:50000
ExePath=C:\path\to\php-cgi.exe
Arguments=-c "C:\path\to\php.ini"
IdleTimeout=9000000
ActivityTimeout=900000
RequestTimeout=900000
InstanceMaxRequests=50000
```

I have noticed that I can successfully load `phpinfo` but just not a symfony2 page

Has anyone come across this issue before? Or has any advice for me on what to try?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have any log in your app/logs project folder?

Comment: Yes, all the log contains is just debug messages, which the last one is "event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener ... "but this is not an application issue as i can change the controller and still get the same fastcgi error but on a completely line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seemed that it was a problem with PHP 5.3.9, I downgraded to 5.3.6 and everything is now running as expected